# Angular JS detail search

Tags: angularjs, crud

Angular JS newbee question.

I've a controller to obtain data from database:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myAppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$http.get("views/resumen.pedidos.php")
.success(function (data) {
    $scope.results = data;

});
```

This data is displayed in a table:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myAppCtrl" class="row top-row">
        <table id="data-table" border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table panel">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th>PEDIDO</th>
                   <th>ESTADO WEB</th>
                   <th>FECHA</th>
                   <th>HORA</th>
                   <th>PREPARAR</th>
                   <th>CANTIDAD</th>
                   <th>PREPARADO</th>
                   <th>ENVIO</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr ng-repeat="result in results">
                     <td>{{ result.pedido }}</td>
                     <td>{{ result.estado_web | uppercase }}</td>
                     <td>{{ result.fecha }}</td>
                     <td>{{ result.hora }}</td>
                     <td>{{ result.preparar }}</td>
                     <td>{{ result.cantidad }}</td>
                     <td>{{ result.enviado }}</td>
                     <td>{{ result.envio }}
                   </tr>
              </tbody>
         </table>
     </div>
 </body>
```

I want to display data from other controller when table row is clicked, using {{ result.pedido }} as key value.

```
app.controller('myAppDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$http.get("views/detalle.pedidos.php")
.success(function (data) {
    $scope.results = data;

});
```

Comment: You have two options, First: when click the row, inject the row data into a service and get it the data from this service. Two: Pass the data by url and get it using `$location.search();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this using a service to pass data to another controller.

```
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="result in results" ng-click="injectDataOnService(result)">
                 <td>{{ result.pedido }}</td>
                 <td>{{ result.estado_web | uppercase }}</td>
                 <td>{{ result.fecha }}</td>
                 <td>{{ result.hora }}</td>
                 <td>{{ result.preparar }}</td>
                 <td>{{ result.cantidad }}</td>
                 <td>{{ result.enviado }}</td>
                 <td>{{ result.envio }}
        </tr>
   </tbody>
```

In the first Controller set the data into de service:

```
...
    $scope.injectDataOnService = function(data){
         myService.setData(data);
    }
...
```

The functions in the service:

```
...    

myService.$inject = ['$q'];

function myService($q){
    var myData = null;

    return {
       setData: setData,
       getData: getData
    }

    function setData(data){
        myData = data;
    }

    function getData(){
        var defered = $q.defer();
        defered.resolve(myData);
        return defered.promise;
    }
}
```

In the second controller, you need inject the service and call getData function:

```
...
myService.getData().then(function(result){
    datafromTable = result;
});
...
```